# What's the proper syntax to query a string in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

When I use the Query function like this using a number, it returns the correct results:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A1:B12,"select B where A matches '1200'", 0)
```

But, when I try to match a string, the result is always an empty output:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A1:B12,"select B where A matches 'qwerty'", 0)
```

This seems ultra-simple, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.. What exactly is the correct syntax to match the string? I've included an example of my problem here: [sheets_query](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oYvMapShWrmyqfT8O_wHwanDdkzzVdQ88ZFJXyGnu9k/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you format ColumnA of Sheet2 as Plain text.

Answer (score 1):

This indeed is simple, instead of matches, you need to use an "=" symbol. So your formula will be `=QUERY(Sheet2!A1:B12,"select B where A='qwerty'", 0)`

Comment: Did you check the example I included?  Your suggestion doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

for number it would be:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A1:B12, "select B where A = 1200", 0)
```

for text, it would be:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A1:B12, "select B where A = 'qwerty'", 0)
```

for number with external reference:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A1:B12, "select B where A ="&1200, 0)
```

for text with external reference:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A1:B12, "select B where A = '"&"qwerty"&"'", 0)
```

for mixed data you can either format it as Plain text or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(Sheet2!A1:B12), "select Col2 where Col1 = 'qwerty'", 0))
```